# Can you create a switch with multiple expressions?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I was wondering if I can use a switch with multiple expressions. For example:

```
string s = "A";
int i = 3;

switch (s, i)
{
    case "A", 1:
      //DoStuff
      break;
    case "A", 2:
      //DoStuff
      break;
    case "A", 3:
      //DoStuff
      break;
    ...
}
```

I don't want to use hundreds of `if(s == "A" && i == 1)`-Statements so it would be great if there's a better solution.

PS: This switch is just an example, I'm actually using it with more complex strings like Names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can, for example by using tuples:

```
string s = "A";
int    i = 3;

switch (s, i)
{
    case ("A", 1):
        // DoStuff.
        break;

    case ("A", 2):
        // DoStuff.
        break;

    case ("A", 3):
        // DoStuff.
        break;
}
```

(Basically exactly what you typed, except with the addition of parenthesis in the cases to make them into tuples.)

Note that this requires C# 7 or later.

Answer (score 3):

Since C# 7, it is possible to do the following:

```
string s = "A";
int i = 3;

switch (s)
{
    case "A" when i == 1:
      //DoStuff
      break;
    case "A" when i == 2:
      //DoStuff
      break;
    case "A" when i == 3:
      //DoStuff
      break;
    ...
}
```